# Raw HTML inside ngOnInit()

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to know how can I use raw HTML tags inside the `ngOnInit()`. For example, normally I could use something like that:

```
element.whateverIwant + '<br>';
```

But when I use it inside of `ngOnInit()` the `<br>` becomes just normal text.

Comment: That's Angular's security preventing risky content injection. If you're sure the content is OK, tell Angular you know that using the [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 html binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding)

Comment: Ohhh... but what if I want to keep the security in place, how should I do this right then? Perhaps using some other way for output?

Comment: How should you do *what* right? It's unclear precisely what you're trying to achieve - please [edit] to give context. And read the answers on the suggested dupe to see if that clarifies what you need to know.

Comment: pal, I'm trying to output some data with html tags... I showed this with an example... Gonna look at the other question

Comment: `element.whateverIwant` doesn't illustrate much, though, does it? Again, what's the **context**? Where does `element` come from? Either you can trust it, in which case use the DomSanitizer, or you can't, in which case you *why do you want it in the DOM?*

Comment: take the elementRef on your component constructor and set innerHtml on the elementRef.nativeElement.